# Wordpress plugin-only view in homepage

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have that kind of code

> ```
> if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ){
>   echo '
> <html>
> <head>
> <script>
> alert("attention xxxx");
>
> </script>
>
> </head>
> <body>
>
> </body>
> </html>';
> }
> ```

The idea of this plugin is adding pop-up but i want to do int ONLY on homepage.
Someone know how to do it?

It must be a wordpress plugin, I need it for a excercise.

Comment: I'd suggest reading through the Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin for starters. What you have there looks like something you'd put in a template file rather than a plugin.

Comment: @AndyWarren That's not strictly true. This can easily be done in a plugin without touching the theme or template files.

Comment: Sure, it could easily be done in a plugin, but he's echoing out the full HTML tags for the head, body, etc. I may have misunderstood what he's asking fully.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to write it as a function :

```
function pop(){

$div = '<script>';
$div .= 'alert("attention xxxx");';
$div .= '</script>';

echo $div;

}
```

Then after that you need to call your function , use wordpress shortcodes functionality

```
add_shortcode('pop','pop');
```

and use it in the homepage itself as [pop]
or you can also call it in the header.php without using shortcodes

```
  if(is_front_page()){
pop();
}
```

or

```
   if ( is_home() ) {
    pop();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you can do it by adding code ONLY to a plugin and nothing at all to the theme files:

```
function prefix_my_alert() {
    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
        echo '<script>alert("Home Alert!")</script>';
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'prefix_my_alert', 1000);
```